# wpcf7 and GTM event listener -> tag firing problem

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

I have contact form 7 plugin and I am trying to track sucessful form submissions. I created a tag event listener with this code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        dataLayer.push({
          'event' : 'wpcf7successfulsubmit',
          'CF7formID' : event.detail.contactFormId
        });
        }, false );
</script>
```

However, it didn't work. No data layer was created. I embedded the following script in a js console on the contact page:

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'wpcf7successfulsubmit',
  'CF7formID' : event.detail.contactFormId
});
}, false );
```

This creates a datalayer which displays on successful submission.

```
{event: 'wpcf7successfulsubmit', CF7formID: '199', gtm.uniqueEventId: 18}
```

However, the other tag does not fire. The tag does not even appear under "Tags Not Fired On This Event". 2 other tags appear here. There is a variable set up for CF7formID, a trigger, and a tag. See screenshots. 
[Gtm Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRS68.png)[Gtm Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RpN1.png)[GTM tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYh2.png)

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days. Help would be good!

Comment: Why do you want to listen to wpcf7mailsent instead of just wpcf7submit? Is the form configured correctly (not running in non-ajax mode, no other js errors on console)? I don't think your issue is with GTM.

Comment: Most people recommend wpcfmailsent as this happens on a successful form submission. wpcfsubmit is sent regardless of successful submission or not. Looking at the JS console on developer tools only gives the following:

Comment: Actually, I have solved it. It needed to go on global js rather than just on the page.